# Querying through related models in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

If I have:

```
class App(models.Model):
    app_name = models.CharField(...)

class Module(models.Model)
    module_name = models.CharField(...)

class config(models.Model)
    config_date    = models.DateTimeField()
    config_modules = ManyToManyField(Module)
    config_app     = models.ForeignKey(Application)
```

How do I get the apps that have a particular module?

If m is a Module object. I know m.config_set.all() gives me all the 
configurations that have module m.  And this:

```
l = []
for conf in m.config_set.all():
    l.append(conf.config_app.app_name)
```

gives what I want, but is there a more terse syntax to achieve same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
Config.objects.filter(config_modules=m).values('config_app__app_name')
```

hope it help

Comment: Thank you kindly for your reply.   That looked great but when I tried I get an error:  AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via Config instances.  I am using Django 1.11.4 and Python 3.5.1

Comment: Yep.  That did it.  Thank you very much, great.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain distinct apps:

```
config.objects.filter(config_modules=m).distinct(
    'config_app').values('config_app__app_name')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and ditto.

Comment: Ok, if I correct here likewise... it still errors: NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend.  But this might be because I am using sqlite3.  I'll have to turn it into a set to make it unique, or something.  Thanks